# how could I get this overtime to display correctly

Tags: java

I'm trying to get overtime pay to display once an employee works more than 40 hours. Everything else works correctly in my payroll program

This is whats displayed:

> Enter the Employee Name:tom
>
> Enter Hourly Rate: 10
>
> Enter Hours Worked:42
>
> tom's check will amount to
>
> $420.00

As over 40 hours have been worked it should be applying the overtime rate

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.time.*;

public class payroll {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String employeeName, tempVariable;
        double hourlyRate, hoursWorked, payroll, overTime = 1.5;
        BufferedReader myIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Enter the Employee Name:");
        employeeName = myIn.readLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the hourly pay rate: ");
        tempVariable = myIn.readLine();
        hourlyRate = Double.parseDouble(tempVariable);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of hours worked:");
        tempVariable = myIn.readLine();
        hoursWorked = Double.parseDouble(tempVariable);

        payroll = (double) hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
        if (hoursWorked > 40) payroll = (overTime * hourlyRate);
        DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");

        System.out.println(employeeName + "'s check will amount to ");
        System.out.println(money.format(payroll));

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: show an example of what it is doing?

Comment: When I run the program I'm not getting the right amount displayed. It's not calculating overtime when am employee works over 40 hours

Comment: Where do you check if an employee pasts 40 hours? Your overTime field is always equal to 1.5.

Comment: `if(hoursWorked > 40)` im sure you want to put that somewhere in your code

Comment: your overtime is 1.5, so overTime >40 is not used

Comment: Oh that helps! Thanks Kun. I'm just starting off with java lol

Comment: @AidanMcGinn no worries, I think my answer can help you solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(hoursWorked >40) payroll =(overTime * hourlyRate*(hoursWorked-40))+hourlyRate*40;
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah man that's great but can you tell me really quick how you figured (hoursWorked-40))+hourlyRate*40?

Comment: I think your mean is if work more than 40 hours, the payroll should be as 1.5 times as normal rate right? So I use the total work hours - 40 which is the overtime, and multiplied by the time(1.5), + what you should get in 40 hours, this 40 hours should be treated as normal rate. That's my understanding.

Comment: Yeah that's great!! Thanks (= learned more from ya in 2 seconds than my old instructor ahah

Answer (score 0):

you have overtime equal to 1.5.  Then you are checking to see if 1.5 > hoursworked.  Unless the person works less than 1.5 hours it's not going to display.

I think you want overtime to equal 40 and if it's less than hourswork

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

As mentioned in the comments, you're comparing `overTime` to `40`, after having set `overTime = 1.5`. Thus, it is never true.
I'm guessing you wanted something more along the lines of

```
if (hoursWorked > 40) ...
```

Secondly, your computation seems off.
If you only fix the test, you'll end up having `payroll = overTime * hourlyRate`, without taking into account the number of hours worked.
I'm guessing you want the overtime to be paid at `1.5` times the hourly rate, and in this case, you'd want to pay 40 hours at the hourly rate plus the overtime (*i.e.* the number of hours worked minus 40) at 1.5 times the hourly rate:

```
if (hoursWorked > 40) {
  payroll = ( 40 * hourlyRate ) + ( ( hoursWorked - 40 ) * overTime * hourlyRate )
}
```

The outer parenthesis are only there for clarity, operator precedence makes them unnecessary.

Furthermore,  you should use a constant for 40, and you might want to rename your `overTime` variable to something along the lines of `overTimeMultiplier`, so as to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Thanks for explaining  that to me (=